# Can't set precision and scale on decimal when creating SQL Server CE table with NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate, sql-server-ce, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using NHibernate mapping by code to create tables both on server (SQL Server 2008) and client (SQL Server CE 3.5).

This one column

```
Property(x => x.Latitude, c =>
                       {
                         c.Precision(10); 
                         c.Scale(8); 
                         c.NotNullable(false);
                       });
```

works excellently on the server where it generates a `decimal(10,8)`.

But on the SQL Server CE client it generates a `numeric(19,0)`? Am I doing something wrong in the mapping here? I'm using NHibernate 3.3.2.

Comment: Are you using the NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCeDialect dialect?

Comment: yes:
configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, typeof(MsSqlCeDialect).AssemblyQualifiedName);
            configuration.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, typeof(SqlServerCeDriver).AssemblyQualifiedName);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved (NHibernate 3.3.3)
Details can be found here:
https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2979

Answer (score 0):

Filed an issue for this in the NHibernate Jira tracker.

Workaround for now is to use real type in the DB:

```
Property(x => x.Longitude, c =>
        {
            c.Column(x => x.SqlType("real"));
            c.NotNullable(false);
        });
        Property(x => x.Latitude, c =>
        {
            c.Column(x => x.SqlType("real"));                
            c.NotNullable(false);
        });
```

The C# properties are still Decimal.